# Learning two SVM simultaneously

Tags: svm

I have a problem where I need to learn two SVM simultaneously. Let me explain: I have a training dataset of N examples, a subset of this examples must be classified by a SVM s1, a second subset of the training examples must be classified by another SVM s2 and a third subset of the examples must be classified by both s1 and s2. I want to learn the two SVM simultaneously (not separately). I wonder how to formulate this problem. We have to maximize the margin of the two SVM and define a set of constraints of each of the SVM. Do you know some papers focusing on a similar problem?